# Squid Proxy Problem

Tags: networking, proxy, squid

Hi Stackoverflow Community

Having a little problem with Squid proxy. For some reason, it won't establish a connection from my computer to the proxy. I'm using Proxifier Portable to establish the connection. I suspected it's something wrong with my config file, so I thought of sending it here. Please view the images below.

Here's the text if that's preferred other than screenshots:

```
http_port 3128
cache deny all
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

access_log none
cache_store_log none
cache_log /dev/null

refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0% 0
refresh_pattern . 0 20% 4320

acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

acl SSL_ports port 1-65535
acl Safe_ports port 1-65535
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl siteblacklist dstdomain "/etc/squid/blacklist.acl"
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager

http_access deny !Safe_ports

http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access deny siteblacklist
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd

auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Squid proxy-caching web server
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
acl password proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow password
http_access deny all

forwarded_for off
request_header_access Allow allow all
request_header_access Authorization allow all
request_header_access WWW-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Content-Length allow all
request_header_access Content-Type allow all
request_header_access Date allow all
request_header_access Expires allow all
request_header_access Host allow all
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all
request_header_access Last-Modified allow all
request_header_access Location allow all
request_header_access Pragma allow all
request_header_access Accept allow all
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all
request_header_access Content-Language allow all
request_header_access Mime-Version allow all
request_header_access Retry-After allow all
request_header_access Title allow all
request_header_access Connection allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Connection allow all
request_header_access User-Agent allow all
request_header_access Cookie allow all
request_header_access All deny allroot
```

[my config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaCv6.png)

[the last part of my config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w17iW.png)

If anyone could help, that would be great.

Comment: @muru Sorry, my Ubuntu knowledge isn't amazing so didn't know how to copy and paste all the code via nano to here. My bad. In the future will do it via text though. (PS: Due to certain restrictions I'm using PuTTY right now, I normally use cmd, it was a last minute kind of thing, sorry about that)

Comment: @muru Added it as text now.

Comment: Thank you! Do the Squid logs indicate that a connection attempt was made?